# if-else efficiency in onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I have a list of 100 items desplayed in RecyclerView.

1 - the Item - the item description

...

100 - the Item - the item description

I want only item 100's number to be smaller, so that "100" aligns nicely with the 2 digit numbers before it.

onBindViewHolder I know I can do an "if the number == 100 make the size smaller" type of thing, but **is there a more efficient way?** Because for 99 times, the if will be skipped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be almost ignorable if-else in terms of efficiency. So, you may use it. But the best practice is to make a viewType for that and check the view type in your onCreateViewHolder(...) to inflate your desire layout for that number. [Have a look on this example.](https://medium.com/@ruut_j/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-bce7fbd1d30e)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use if-else in onBindViewHolder to show only needful data for a user.

Comment: Yes, I was asking if there was a more efficient alternative to if-else in my case. I thought it would be a waste to check 100 times when 99 times were not needed.